# New messages was not consuming after RuntimeException in SessionAwareMessageListener

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I have a problem with spring jms `SessionAwareMessageListener`

When I add `RedeliveryPolicy` to `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` my messages is correct redelivering, but all next messages (new messages) is stuck and not consuming (class Listener not invoked)

Please, help, whats wrong in my code?

My JmsPublisher:

```
    @Component
    public class DocumentMsgSender {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;


    public void send(DocumentMsgTemplate message) throws JMSException {
        jmsTemplate.send(new DocMsgCreator(message));
    }


    class DocMsgCreator implements MessageCreator {
        DocumentMsgTemplate message;

        public DocMsgCreator(DocumentMsgTemplate message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session s) throws JMSException {
            Message resultMessage = s.createObjectMessage(message);
            resultMessage.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
            resultMessage.setJMSPriority(9);
            return resultMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

My Jms listner :

```
    @Service
    public class DocumentMsgListener implements SessionAwareMessageListener<Message> {
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate sendDocJmsTemplate;

    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
        throw new RuntimeException("ERROR");
    }
}
```

My ActiveMQConnectionFactory is

```
    @Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(env.getProperty("activemq.url"));
    connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(getRedeliveryPolicy());
    connectionFactory.setMessagePrioritySupported(true);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

RedeliveryPolicy

```
    private RedeliveryPolicy getRedeliveryPolicy() {
    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(900000L);
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(900000L);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(48);
    return redeliveryPolicy;
}
```

My DefaultMessageListenerContainer is

```
   @Bean
@Autowired
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(DocumentMsgListener messageListener) {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    container.setDestinationName("testQueue");
    container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
    container.setSessionTransacted(true);
    return container;
}
```

My JmsTemplate:

```
    @Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("testQueue");
    jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
    jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is

connectionFactory.setNonBlockingRedelivery(true);